# Add an overlay (video or text) to multicast tv stream

Tags: video, streaming, live

#### What i have

- 10 decoder which subscribe to private multicasted TV channels.
- 10 TV to display what the decoders outputs (connected though HDMI).

#### What i want to do

- I would like to to add an overlay (video or text) on the TV.
- The overlay must be present on every TV channels.

#### My guesses

I first though about using OBS on a computer between each decoder and tv. To merge RTMP and overlay. And put OBS in fullscreen-preview mode.

```
|---------|         |-------------|         |--------|
| decoder |--HDMI-->|   computer  |--HDMI-->|   TV   |
|---------|         | running OBS |         |--------|
                    |-------------|
```

But this is not the ideal scenario, because i'll have to restart and put OBS in fullscreen everytime the computer is shutted down...


So my question is, how would you achieve this (with OSb or something else)?